# Why is the infinite product of this quotient of $\sin$'s equal to $\left(\frac{3}{\pi}\right)^{2}$[SOLVED]

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, infinite-product

I was intrigued by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1514908/225848) the other day, but perhaps lack a little bit of the necessary background to understand a certain step.

Namely, the fact that 
$$\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6\cdot 2^{n-1}}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6\cdot 2^n}\right)}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{3}{\pi}\right)^{2}$$
is used, and I cannot make sense of this at all. Jack D'Aurizio comments that "*the product of squares is the square of the product*" but I'm not entirely sure what this means. Can anyone explain it to me a little more in-depth? I'm not sure what to look up to understand this foreign concept.

**Edit**: With a hint from Simon S I got the answer, so I have to thank him very much. I'm not sure what to do with my question now.

Comment: "the product of squares is the square of the product" just means (ab)^2 = a^2 b^2

Comment: @Simpson17866 Oh, wow, just that. Well I distribute the square over the quotient, but it doesn't seem to help me evaluate the infinite product any easier.

Comment: Edit the title with SOLVED in bracket

Comment: @KprimeX Thanks, I will.

Comment: @WeiYing If I might give a suggestion, it would be helpful if you would answer your own question by explaining how you solved your question in the Answer box.

Comment: @Hrodelbert Oh alright, for sure. I won't be free for an hour or two but I'll come back and post my findings then, thanks for the suggestion.